# "return;" vs "empty method body"

Tags: java

Does the following two methods internally behaves equal?

**version 1:**

```
@Override
public void doNothing(User user) {
    // nothing to do
    return;
}
```

**version 2:**

```
@Override
public void doNothing(User user) {
    // nothing to do
}
```

Which one should I prefer?

I only want to know if the two methods behave **internally equal**. Simple question:) Nothing more.

Comment: Adding return will exit the method at that point (it could be in a specific condition ) and not execute the remaining code. But the compiler will tell you if you have improper conditions and some part of the code cannot be reached in case you want to return after the execution of some conditional logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use which ever way suits you.  But the generated code will be the same.

```
public class ReturnDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
    }
    
    public void foo() {
        int a = 10;
    }
    
    public void bar() {
        int a = 10;
        return;
    }
}

 // Method descriptor #6 ()V
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 2
  public void foo();
    0  bipush 10
    2  istore_1 [a]
    3  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 9]
        [pc: 3, line: 10]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 4] local: this index: 0 type: stackOverflow.ReturnDemo
        [pc: 3, pc: 4] local: a index: 1 type: int
  
  // Method descriptor #6 ()V
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 2
  public void bar();
    0  bipush 10
    2  istore_1 [a]
    3  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 13]
        [pc: 3, line: 14]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 4] local: this index: 0 type: stackOverflow.ReturnDemo
        [pc: 3, pc: 4] local: a index: 1 type: int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 is the standard. Don't think I have ever seen version 1 in java code outside of loops.

Why should you write a keyword that has no benefits and just increases the size of your methods/classes?

Comment: I don't know how java will treat such things **internally**. Maybe, for example, the one has faster method execution than the other.

Comment: @nimo23  There are far more important things that that to worry about.  Besides a method must return when it is done whether you put a return there or not.

Comment: I only want to know if the two methods behave internally equal. Simple question:) Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `return` if it's the last statement, so version 2 is always preferred. But other than that, the compiler should optimize the unnecessary `return` away.

It's a different story when you need to exit the method prematurely, for example:

```
public void doSomething(String value) {
    if (value == null) {
        return;
    }
    
    // else do something with 'value', which would misbehave if it were null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you compile a class like

```
public class A {
  public void first() {
  }
  public void second() {
    return;
  }
}
```

and disassemble the generated code (`javap -c A`), you will obtain something like:

```
public class A {
  public A();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void first();
    Code:
       0: return

  public void second();
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

as you can see, both methods are identical - the compiler adds a `return` at the end of the first method (similar to adding the default constructor).